# Store More than 100 Millions Records in memory C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am using C# DataTable to store around **100 Millions records**. but after storing 16 millions it throws an exception "**out of memory**"

So can we store 100 milions record in c# datatable or do we have another alternative for that.

After storing data that i want to perform some LINQ queries on that data.

Please provide me the solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040523/total-rows-that-we-can-add-to-datatable

Comment: What is the point in having 100 million records in memory? It doesn't makes much sense for me. Where do you get the data from? Why can't you perform the Linq queries(to filter) from your data source itself (DB, file or whatver)?

Comment: Out of interest, how large is each record, and how much memory do you have? Even without the DataTable restriction, if you have 100 million records and each just has a string with 20 characters, with the overhead of a `DataRow` object etc I'd still expect that to be *at least* 100 bytes per row, and therefore 10GB. Why would you need to have your whole database in memory?

Comment: Here is no issue of memory. I am creating this solution for the machine having 64 GB Ram. And we are not gonna have any Database on which i can perform the Direct LINQ operation. The rows in datatable will be multiply at run time.. and it may cross 100 millions.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216.

Found on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

Alternate is, Use a dataset. Create a databale after each 16 million record and add that in dataset.

Comment: Yes i know that ... but do we have any alternative for that ????

Comment: use dataset and create a new datatable after each 16 million record

Comment: That will not complete my need... as i require all records in one List or in one collection.